# Why should NASA send a poet to space?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, contact

In the 1997 movie [***Contact***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884/), Jodie Foster’s character says, “They should have sent a poet.” Why should NASA send a poet to space?

Answer (score 7):

### Because only a poet could do justice to the beauty of the experience.

Ellie [says](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=contact)...

> No words!
>   No words...
>   ...to describe it!
>   Poetry!
>   They should have sent...
>   ...a poet.
>   It's so beautiful!
>   Beautiful!
>   So beautiful.
>   I had no idea.

Comment: How do you know all the movies???

Comment: Because I watch them...and have been for a long time.

Comment: Well, I also watch many movies, but remember them all is very hard.